# reading a /dev/input/eventX file in Android and displaying its contents in TextView

Tags: java, android, file-io, runnable

**UPDATE3:** I am trying to read from `/dev/input/eventX` file. When I read contents of this file, I see special characters in TextView. I wish to see binary (1's and 0's). Still having trouble unfortunately. Any help would be very appreciated!

**Summary:** I am trying to read `/dev/input/event1` in Android OS 4.4 (KitKat). I then want to display this data in TextView on the GUI.

*Note:*
I know that I need to gain permissions to the file. Although I haven't written it in the code for now (for simplicity), I have successfully gained permission to the file via the terminal (`chmod 666`).

**MainActivity:** I call the function to read my file and then update the results in a TextView here.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    runThread();
    }

    private void runThread() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                getEvent.readEvent();
                                result = getEvent.logGetEventData();                              
                             textView.setText(getString(R.string.result_display, 
                             result));
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {                        
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

**GetEvent:** I gain root privileges and read my file here.

```
public class GetEvent {

    private File file = new File("/dev/input/event1");

    public void readEvent()    {
        {
            try {
                mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                fin.read(bytes);
                s = new String(bytes); 
            }              
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                try {
                    if (fin != null) {
                        fin.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }              
            }
        }
    }

    public String logGetEventData() {
            retour = s;
            return (retour);
    }
}
```

Comment: `(mostly just crashes). I`. Stack trace please.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {

        }`. So you leave that empty? You dont wanno know if this happens?

Comment: `I call the function to read my file and`. You are not doing that.

Comment: `private GetEvent getEvent;`. Uninitialised variable.

Comment: Thanks very much greenapps! Doesn't crash anymore. However, still not seeing anything. I just see a blank screen. Perhaps it's having issue printing out the binary/hex in the file? Not sure. Will keep investigating and running tests. Please let me know if you have any further suggestions/comments.